# Which blockchain platform supports user defined consensus protocol for particular use case?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to implement a new consensus protocol similar to Proof of stake. However, here my stake would be some value results from different mechanisms. I am wondering whether I could use any open-source blockchain for that? For example, Hyperledger or Ethereum, etc.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parity has [pluggable consensus engines](https://openethereum.wiki/Pluggable-Consensus/).

Comment: I heard that Hyperledger also supports pluggable consensus protocol too. Do you have any idea about that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I do not know about Hyperledger. All I know it was IBM led effort and it is not doing well https://www.coindesk.com/ibm-blockchain-revenue-misses-job-cuts-sources

Comment: I have searched a lot about Parity Ethereum implementation from scratch in a private environment, but could not find any that works. Do you know any tutorials or documentation that might help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the source code. Your use case is so niche that it is not worth of writing documentation for. Everyone who gets involved this needs to understand the node software source code anyways.

Comment: Hi Mikko, The documentation of parity is not that rich. However, I find Substrate Parity which ahs a great documentation. I believe you know that but if you not you may check that out.